# AngularJS directive race condition (order of listeners?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive that listens to change events on inputs that are bubbled up (using jQuery's [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function). I'm having an issue where the listener is being fired before the ng-models update (in Chrome), which means the data is stale within my directive. It seems to work in Firefox ok. Does this have to do with the order of listeners being attached? An example:

The HTML:

```
<div my:change="myChange()">
    <input type="checkbox" ng:change="ngChange()" ng:model="foo" ng:true-value="foo" ng:false-value="bar" />
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.foo = 'foo'; // Source
  $scope.bar = 'foo'  // w/o $timeout
  $scope.bar2 = 'foo' // with $timout

  $scope.ngChange = function() {

    console.log('ngChange');
  }

})
.directive('myChange', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

     $element.delegate('input', 'change', function(event) {

       console.log('myChange')

       // A value was changed, let's update the value from the model.
       $timeout(function() {
         $scope.bar2 = $scope.foo;
       })

       $scope.bar = $scope.foo;
     })
    }
  }

}]);
```

When the checkbox is checked `$scope.foo` should be updated. the `ngChange` gets called first in FF, second in Chrome, where as `myChange` gets called first Chrome and second in FF.

Adding the `$timeout` call makes it work as expected (`$scope.foo` has the value I expect), but that feels like a major hack.

Working plunkr of code above: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1TWGKlkimS3H5Lqaisw

Comment: Any chance the Angular jqLite [version of .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) meet your needs?  Then you wouldn't have to try to get consistent timing between jQuery and Angular across browsers- which clearly has it's tricky spots.

Comment: @KayakDave It's not ideal for what I'm trying to do. I'm using the delegate function so that I can get the old "live" functionality. There are also tons of inputs and I rather listen for events that bubble then add tons of ng:click and ng:change

Comment: $timeout may be your best bet.  I know what you mean about it feeling like a hack.  But since (with a timeout of 0) it adds a new event to the very end of browser event queue- it seems like it effectively does what you want.  And it's a not uncommon solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing $element to $($element)? See below...

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.foo = 'foo'; // Source
  $scope.bar = 'foo'  // w/o $timeout
  $scope.bar2 = 'foo' // with $timout

  $scope.ngChange = function() {

    console.log('ngChange');
  }

})
.directive('myChange', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

     $($element).delegate('input', 'change', function(event) {

       console.log('myChange')

       // An value was changed, let's update the value from the model.
       $timeout(function() {
         $scope.bar2 = $scope.foo;
       })

       $scope.bar = $scope.foo;
     })
    }
  }

}]);
```

Comment: Just tried it, it does not seem to make a difference. $element is already a jQuery object.